# How would I hide an object from a specific camera in Godot 3D?

Tags: game-development, godot, masking, gdscript, culling

I'm working on a multiplayer horror game in Godot and I want to make it so you can't see your own body but others can. I heard about culling masks for this but I have no idea how they work and if what I'm trying to achieve is possible using them. The body is a `Skeleton` node and others should be able to see it but my camera (a sibling of the skeleton node) shouldn't be able to. Could someone explain how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Not familiar enough with 3D to actually directly send an answer, but can't you just call hide() on your skeleton node so it is not visible? Obviously just call it on the instance the player is controlling and not for the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Skeleton` is not visible. However, you must have some children `VisualInstance`s (usually `MeshInstance`) which are actually visible.

In the usual setup, you have a `Skeleton` node, with multiple `MeshInstance` as children, which also have their `skeleton` property set to the `Skeleton` node.

---

I don't know how you are setting up your multiplayer, but if it is not split-screen you probably can swap or remove the player character but not those of the other players. If removing the `Skeleton` is not viable, you should still be able to remove or hide its children `VisualInstance`s.

---

Anyway, if you do need to setup multiple cameras, you can se the `layers` on the `MeshInstance` (or whatever `VisualInstance` you are using) and the `cull_mask` on the `Camera`. If they overlap (they have common bit flags) then the `Camera` will render that `MeshInstance`, otherwise it wont.

See also [Hide an object for a specific camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67410706/402022).

Comment: Thanks so much, the cull_mask and layers trick worked